# pandas multiindex DataFrame from list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested, multi-index

I have a list of nested dictionaries

```
lst = [{'a':{'aa':1,'ab':2},'b':{'ba':3,'bb':4}}]*2
```

I am struggling to get a pandas DataFrame with mutltiindex columns.

Currently I am doing:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct,orient='index').stack().to_frame().T for dct in lst])
```

and the output is (and shall be)
[image]

But there got to be a simpler line I guess, this one is ugly, cannot figure out right now. Any help is welcome. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested list with dict comprehension and then recreate `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{(k,k1): v1 for k, v in x.items() for k1, v1 in v.items()} for x in lst])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
print (df)
   a     b   
  aa ab ba bb
0  1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4
```